Flutter Device Calendar Plugin Bug
Future<void> addToCalendar(String meetingTitle, DateTime startDate, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) async {
    // Construct the Event object
    var event = Event(
      "1",
      title: meetingTitle,
      start: TZDateTime.from(startDate.add(Duration(hours: startTime.hour)).add(Duration(minutes: startTime.minute)), tz.getLocation('Asia/Singapore')),
      end: TZDateTime.from(startDate.add(Duration(hours: endTime.hour)).add(Duration(minutes: endTime.minute)), tz.getLocation('Asia/Singapore')),
    );

    // Call the createOrUpdateEvent method from the device calendar plugin
    try {
      final result = await _deviceCalendarPlugin.createOrUpdateEvent(event);
      if (result?.isSuccess == true) {
        print('Event added/updated successfully');
      } else {
        print('Failed to add/update event: ${result?.data}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error adding/updating event: $e');
    }
  }

it is a scheduling training feature, when scheduling, it will added date, start time and end time into device calendar, and it recorded into database with true information, but if I add the training with today date by today,
For example today is 5/3, I add the training with 5/3 also, when it recorded into the device calendar, it will shifted to the next day and the time is about shifted after 17 hours
but the thing is for other date it works fine, only today date got bug
but the thing is for other date it works fine, only today date got bug
